# Add SCDF (Spring Cloud Data Flow) Application to Bitnami chart generated cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've used the [Bitnami Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow) to install SCDF into a k8s cluster generated by kOps in AWS.

I'm trying to add my development SCDF stream apps into the installation using a file URI and cannot figure-out where or how the shared Skipper & Server mount point is. exec'ing into either instance there is no `/home/cnb` and I'm not seeing anything common via `mount`. The best I can tell the Bitnami installation is using the MariaDB instance for shared "storage".

Is there a recommended way of installing local/dev Stream apps into the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the previous answer here is what I came-up with:

1. Create an EBS Volume
2. Mount it on each EC2 instance in the cluster at the same location (`/cdf`)
3. Install CDF using the Bitnami chart and this config file:

```
server.extraVolumeMounts:
      # Locstion in container
    - mountPath: /applications 
      # Refer to the volume below
      name: application-volume
server.extraVolumes:
  - name: application-volume
    hostPath:
      # Location in host filesystem
      path: /cdf
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
skipper.extraVolumeMounts:
      # Locstion in container
    - mountPath: /applications 
      # Refer to the volume below
      name: application-volume
skipper.extraVolumes:
  - name: application-volume
    hostPath:
      # Location in host filesystem
      path: /cdf
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

Then I can copy my jars into `/cdf` on the host file system and install the applications using a file URI of `file:///applications/<jar-file-name>` and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of parameters under the `deployer` section that allows you to mount volumes ([link](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/c351211a5501bb44b5e065a5e3a7d4b7414f84f3/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow/values.yaml#L788)):

```yaml
deployer:
   ## @param deployer.volumeMounts Streaming applications extra volume mounts
   ##
   volumeMounts: {}
   ## @param deployer.volumes Streaming applications extra volumes
   ##
   volumes: {}
```

see https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow#deployer-parameters.

Then, the mounted volume is used in the ConfigMaps (both server and skipper):

- Server
  https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/c351211a5501bb44b5e065a5e3a7d4b7414f84f3/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow/templates/server/configmap.yaml#L60
- Skipper
  https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/c351211a5501bb44b5e065a5e3a7d4b7414f84f3/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow/templates/skipper/configmap.yaml#L72

Apart from that, there are also `server.extraVolumes` and `server.extraVolumeMounts` to be set on the Dataflow Server Pod, and `skipper.extraVolumes` and `skipper.extraVolumeMounts` to be set on the Skipper Pod just in case it's useful for your use case.

Comment: Thanks. I saw those and thought they'd be useful, where I was stumped was the lack of `/home/cnb` in the container. Am I correct that the volume mount will create the container mount point and I don't need a pre-existing mount like `/home/cnb`?